# Creating an array or lists of lists in R

Tags: r

I have a list of matrices such that `my_list[[1]]` consists of a matrix and `my_list[[2]]` contains another matrix and so on. I want to embed this list inside a loop such that for every iteration of the loop I have a different my_list with different matrices, and want to be able to access them later. Is there any way I could do this in R? For example like creating an array (of size = number of iterations of the loop), and each index of the array would have a different list of matrices. Or something similar. And how can I access it. Could anyone please help me with this? I would greatly appreciate the help. I have looked around but cannot find a way to do this. Lists of lists seem to be an option, and I have tried to experiment with it for one iteration but it gives this error:

```
> nes <- list()    
> nes[[1]] <- append(nes[[1]], my_list[[1]])
Error in nes[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Would be great if anyone could help me with this.

EDIT: 
Basically what I have is an initial list known as particles. Something like this:

```
    for (k in 1:10)
    {
      # three centroids; k = 3
      particle[[k]] <- rbind(features.dataf[sample(1:10, 1),2:4],
                           features.dataf[sample(1:10, 1),2:4],
                           features.dataf[sample(1:10, 1),2:4])
      row.names(particle[[k]]) <- c(1,2,3)
    }

Then I run this loop again. With an extra outer loop.
for (n in 1:30) {
for (k in 1:10) {
  ###some calculations
  ### create a vector f[k] with an f value for each k (calculated according to some formula)
  pbestFitness[n,k] <- f[k] ##create a nXk dataframe that stores the f[k] value for every iteration of n
 ### over here I want to create a list of lists 

}
}
```

In the above code where I create the list of lists, such that for every iteration of the outer loop I have a particle[[k]]th matrix stored. 
Any particle[[k]] is of the form:

```
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.96436532 0.8958297 0.6089338
[2,] 0.08555853 0.7762849 0.6647247
[3,] 0.30792817 0.8061227 0.5099790
```

The desired output would be something like that if I try to access this new lists of lists (nes), its nes[[n]] value should have a list with k number of matrices.

Comment: Rather try: `nes <- append(nes, my_list[[1]])`. Reason is that append take `nes` and will add a new element (the list can be empty or have some elements it does not matter). Whereas in your code you consider `nes[[1]]` already exists and you add an element to the first element of nes. But your list is empty, hence returning this error.

Comment: Btw can you show a simple input with 2/3 small matrix and the desired output?

Comment: Thank you! It does not seem to give any error but could you please also explain how can I access this new lists for example if I want to access the kth list inside the nth value of nes, how can I do it? When I try to access nes[[1]], it just gives me the first element of the my_list[[1]]. And suppose there were additional my_list[[2]] present, how can I access that. I've edited the post, please let me know if any further clarification is needed.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I just did above, could you let me know which particular part should I explain again. `particle[[k]]` is a list that I am generating in the first loop. It has the sample input. I next want to introduce another outer loop (as shown above) such that the 1st element of nes would contain one list particle[[k]] (which varies from 1 to 10), and the 2nd element of nes would contain another list particle[[k]] which would contain different matrices.

Comment: This is still unclear, I do not want to shake my brain for such a question ... just provide SIMPLE inputs like an explicit list of 3/4 matrix of 2 dimensions for example. And show what you want exactly as output.

Comment: I apologize. I think I figured out the solution. What I was having problem with was figuring out the exact syntax of creating a list within a list. So I do something like this `nes[[n]] <- particle` instead of `nes[[n]] <- particle[[k]]` And then access the matrix within the particle list by a simple syntax of `nes[[n]][[k]]`. Thank you for your help!